# Wordpress: avoid pages being listed in a widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that uses 2 pages for a specific purpose.

When I create the two pages manually with a template that I created they are listed as links on the main page but I don't want them to be shown. How can I avoid them to be shown?

Can I change something on my template so that they are not shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages or tweak http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages for a theme that doesn't use WP3 menus, or exclude pages within the menu system in a WP3-compatible theme.

But trying to exclude pages when your plugin is used by other people is going to run into problems. How can you consistently exclude pages in all circumstances? What happens if someone already has a page named the same as the pages your plugin generates?

Comment: The exclude-pages worked like a charm, just what I was looking for, thanks songdogtech!

Comment: Regarding your questions, I'm using a specific template for the pages I'm generating and also the page names. If there is already a page with the same name I will let the plugin choose another name but the name is not gonna be a common name like "about" or "contact", will have a restrictive name. Thanks for your advice